# Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBr-PybP_9c&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified) Tutorial for build WhatsApp clone, but i'm using latest version of React and react-router-dom,

And whenever i'm start new conversation it should renders this component, instead of that, it renders nothing.

`OpenConversation.js`

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Form, InputGroup, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useConversations } from '../contexts/ConversationsProvider';

export default function OpenConversation() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const setRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node) {
      node.scrollIntoView({ smooth: true })
    }
  }, [])
  const { sendMessage, selectedConversation } = useConversations()

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    sendMessage(
      selectedConversation.recipients.map(r => r.id),
      text
    )
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
      <div className="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start justify-content-end px-3">
          {selectedConversation.messages.map((message, index) => {
            const lastMessage = selectedConversation.messages.length - 1 === index
            return (
              <div
                ref={lastMessage ? setRef : null}
                key={index}
                className={`my-1 d-flex flex-column ${message.fromMe ? 'align-self-end align-items-end' : 'align-items-start'}`}
              >
                <div
                  className={`rounded px-2 py-1 ${message.fromMe ? 'bg-primary text-white' : 'border'}`}>
                  {message.text}
                </div>
                <div className={`text-muted small ${message.fromMe ? 'text-right' : ''}`}>
                  {message.fromMe ? 'You' : message.senderName}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="m-2">
          <InputGroup>
            <Form.Control
              as="textarea"
              required
              value={text}
              onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
              style={{ height: '75px', resize: 'none' }}
            />
            <InputGroup.Append>
              <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
            </InputGroup.Append>
          </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

And this component is rendered on `Dashboard.js`

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'
import { Form, InputGroup, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { useConversations } from '../contexts/ConversationsProvider';

export default function OpenConversation() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('')
  const setRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (node) {
      node.scrollIntoView({ smooth: true })
    }
  }, [])
  const { sendMessage, selectedConversation } = useConversations()

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    sendMessage(
      selectedConversation.recipients.map(r => r.id),
      text
    )
    setText('')
  }

  return (
    <div className="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1">
      <div className="flex-grow-1 overflow-auto">
        <div className="d-flex flex-column align-items-start justify-content-end px-3">
          {selectedConversation.messages.map((message, index) => {
            const lastMessage = selectedConversation.messages.length - 1 === index
            return (
              <div
                ref={lastMessage ? setRef : null}
                key={index}
                className={`my-1 d-flex flex-column ${message.fromMe ? 'align-self-end align-items-end' : 'align-items-start'}`}
              >
                <div
                  className={`rounded px-2 py-1 ${message.fromMe ? 'bg-primary text-white' : 'border'}`}>
                  {message.text}
                </div>
                <div className={`text-muted small ${message.fromMe ? 'text-right' : ''}`}>
                  {message.fromMe ? 'You' : message.senderName}
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group className="m-2">
          <InputGroup>
            <Form.Control
              as="textarea"
              required
              value={text}
              onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)}
              style={{ height: '75px', resize: 'none' }}
            />
            <InputGroup.Append>
              <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
            </InputGroup.Append>
          </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

`App.js`

```
import React from 'react'
import Login from './Login'
import useLocalStorage from '../hooks/useLocalStorage';
import Dashboard from './Dashboard'
import { ContactsProvider } from '../contexts/ContactsProvider'
import { ConversationsProvider } from '../contexts/ConversationsProvider';
import { SocketProvider } from '../contexts/SocketProvider';
import TopNavBar from './TopNavBar';

import Signup from "./Signup"
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap"
import { AuthProvider } from "../contexts/AuthContext"
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom"
import PrivateRoute from "./PrivateRoute"
import ForgotPassword from "./ForgotPassword"
import UpdateProfile from "./UpdateProfile"

function App() {
  const [id, setId] = useLocalStorage('id', 0)
  const AuthM = (

    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <TopNavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path="/"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <SocketProvider id={id}>
                  <ContactsProvider>
                    <ConversationsProvider id={id}>
                      <Dashboard id={id} />
                    </ConversationsProvider>
                  </ContactsProvider>
                </SocketProvider>
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          >
          </Route>
          <Route
            path="/update-profile"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <UpdateProfile />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          >
          </Route>
          <Route path="/signup" element={<Signup />} />
          <Route path="/login" element={<Login onIdSubmit={setId} />} />
          <Route path="/forgot-password" element={<ForgotPassword />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
  return (
    AuthM
  )
}

export default App;
```

i'm getting following error when app is trying to render `OpenConversation.js`

> The above error occurred in the  component:
> at div
> at http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:42187:5
> at div
> at http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:41901:5
> at form
> at http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:41543:5
> at div
> at OpenConversation (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:1386:74)
> at div
> at Dashboard (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:451:5)
> at ConversationsProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:3292:5)
> at ContactsProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:3181:5)
> at SocketProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:3498:5)
> at PrivateRoute (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:1572:5)
> at Routes (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:63406:5)
> at Router (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:63339:15)
> at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:62819:5)
> at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/main.710ea063df9fff086c2a.hot-update.js:3032:5)
> at App (http://localhost:3000/main.ae1831d77cead42fa1a1.hot-update.js:56:89)

And this

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `OpenConversation`.

Any idea on what happened there ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start removing sections of the rendered JSX until it goes away. When it goes away you should have a better idea of where your invalid element is coming from.

Comment: @BrianThompson Thank You That worked.....

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to someone else,
As per @BrianThompsons comment, I found it was `<InputGroup.Append>`  causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the exact same tutorial, and had the same issue (and it's not the first time that I've gotten an error while copying the code - there have been some breaking updates since the video came out).

Instead of having `<InputGroup.Append>`, just stick the button inside the `InputGroup`, like so:

```html
    <Form.Group className="m-2">
    <InputGroup>
        <Form.Control
            as="textarea"
            required
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
            style={{ height: '75px', resize: 'none' }}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Send</Button>
    </InputGroup>
    </Form.Group>
```

That put the button next to the text box, as we wanted. Hope that helps.